# Get term by label/name from termSet

Tags: managed-metadata, term, term-set

i want to check if Term is available in termSet programatically by term name or label. if it not available then i want to create it, How i check? I am using this code but does not work, what will be the correct code?

```
if (termSet.GetTerms("MyTerm",false) == null)
                {
                    termSet.CreateTerm("MyTerm", 1033);
                    termStore.CommitAll();
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GetTerms`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee573394(v=office.14).aspx) returns a [TermCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.termcollection(v=office.14).aspx) object, which, even if it's empty, will not be `null`.  You probably want to do something like:

```
TermCollection results = termSet.GetTerms("MyTerm", false);
if (results.Count == 0)
{
    termSet.CreateTerm("MyTerm", 1033);
    termStore.CommitAll();
}
```